# Badge for menu link

Tags: navigation, routes

I am building a Bootstrap 3 sub theme where I want to display some information next to menu link in main menu. I tried to implement `hook_menu_link_alter` in template.php file in following way

```
function mytheme_menu_link_alter(&$item){
if($item['title'] == 'Messages'){
$item['title']= $item['title'].'<span class="badge">X</span>';
}
}
```

but it does not work. The same stuff with `link_title`. Whta should be fixed in code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override the output of [theme_menu_link()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) to produce what you want:

```
function THEME_menu_link(&$variables)
{
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $sub_menu = '';

    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'menu-' . $element['#original_link']['mlid'];

    if ($element['#below'])
    {
        $sub_menu = drupal_render($element['#below']);
    }
    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);


    if($variables['element']['#title'] == 'Messages')
    {
        // to just add the text
        $output .= '<span class="badge">X</span>';

        // to include it as a link
        $output .= l('X', $element['#href'], array('attributes' => array('class' => 'badge')));
    }

    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for idea. I've modified to display `<span>` in a link tag `$element['#title'] .= '<span class="badge">X</span>';`. But instead `<` `>` `"` symbols were converted to html entities. Is there any way to display them as part of html tag?

Comment: Im not sure I understand that last comment - you want to display `<span class="badge">X</span>` as part of the text, as part of the actual href link, or you want to display the X within the <span> as part of the href?

Comment: Link is displayed like <a href="#">Messages&lt;span class=&quot;badge&quot;&gt;X&lt;/span&gt;</a>. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Drupal sanitizes a link - this is a security feature to protect against certain attacks, so I don't think you can incorporate it into a single link - I modified the answer to include an option for creating a separate <a> with the class 'badge' that sits beside the original and directs to the same location. Should be seemless to the end user